# What determines the 'flipped_aes' occurence in ggplot2 objects?

Tags: r, ggplot2, swirl

I am currently writing swirl lessons where im trying to test if a ggplot2 object created by the user is somewhat equal (`all.equal()`) to an object i create in a custom AnswerTest. however the plot object which i receive from swirl api by accessing e$val often inherits an flipped_aes = FALSE attribute which i cannot create in my own plots and hence `all.equal(e$val, someplot)` fails allthough they look equal.

I would really appreciate some ideas how to work around it or control its occurence!

if it occurs all.equal() fails with the following message:

`"Component “layers”: Component 1: Component 4: Length mismatch: comparison on first 2 components"`

my current test looks like this:

```
calculates_same_graph <- function(expression){ #If ggplot expression must be written in curly brackets in Yaml file
   e <- get("e", parent.frame())
   eSnap <- cleanEnv(e$snapshot)
   
   val <- expression
   
   passed <- isTRUE(all.equal(val[-8], e$val[-8]))
   assign("e", e$val, envir = globalenv()) #only for diagnostics, changes 
                                           #when new answer is put in
   return(passed)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I agree that this is a bit weird, but I found out that the `flipped_aes` parameter only comes into existance after printing a plot. The weird bit is that is appears to be an object-modifying side-effect of printing the plot. This only makes sense if the paramter is being cached somehow.

Suppose we have two plots that have opposite aesthetic flipping:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Should have flipped_aes = FALSE
plot1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_col()

# Should have flipped_aes = TRUE
plot2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Species)) +
  geom_col()
```

We can see that these unprinted objects do not have `flipped.aes` in their geom parameters.

```r
# Before printing plot
plot1$layers[[1]]$geom_params
#> $width
#> NULL
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] FALSE

plot2$layers[[1]]$geom_params
#> $width
#> NULL
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] FALSE
```

Now we can print these plots to a temporary file. Just printing it in the console should work too, I just can't replicate that in a reprex.

```r
# Printing as tempfile
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
png(tmp)
plot1
plot2
dev.off()
#> png 
#>   2
unlink(tmp)
```

Now after we've printed the plot, suddenly the plot objects have the `flipped_aes` parameter.

```r
# After printing plot
plot1$layers[[1]]$geom_params
#> $width
#> NULL
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $flipped_aes
#> [1] FALSE

plot2$layers[[1]]$geom_params
#> $width
#> NULL
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $flipped_aes
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I don't know what the best way is to deal with this weirdness in your swirl test, but it appears that the printing of the plot influences that parameter.

Comment: Weird but interesting and insightfull! Thank you so much! I guess it could work if I just remove it from the object since it isnt required to test if the plot was done right. Also i could ask the students to assign their plots to objects (however this is a bad solution since the plots wouldnt be displayed in the same step)